# I want to eliminate values containing "http"

Tags: php, codeigniter, filtering

I want to eliminate values ​​containing "**http**", eg

```
 <iframe src="http://tuto-rial.com/"></iframe>
```

I already get the value of the **src="http://tuto-rial.com/"**, less remove "**http://**" it.

**output** only: "**tuto-rial.com**";

Comment: Please edit & complete the question ????

Comment: Why in hell you would want to do such thing? If your purpose is to close a XSS hole, that is a very poor solution.

Comment: i'm sory, my speak Englis is bad,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this MVC framework and never use it, but I imagine you can actually use PHP str_replace() function in your code.

EDIT:

if the data of your iframe is not on your server, you will need to load external source and then use PHP str_replace() function.

Comment: och,.
I've been able,.
turns using the preg_replace function like this that I made:
'preg_replace ('/^( http:|https:) + (\ /+)/','',$ string);'

regards
@tokoweb